# How to disable image loading on ChromiumWebBrowser?

Tags: cefsharp

I'm using ChromiumWebBrowser in my project, but I don't need the browser load images. I tried to find in `CefSettings` but don't found anything. so how to disable load images?

Comment: BrowserSettings is the name of the class you are looking for

Comment: @amaitland: nice, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disable-image-loading` in `CefCommandLineArgs`. It works for me.

```
public BrowserForm() {
    InitializeComponent();

    var settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-image-loading", "1");
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);

    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("") {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    };   

    Controls.Add(browser);
}
```